# what are the problems we may face if we not handling non-memory resources in java?

Tags: java, oop, garbage-collection

In java, it automatically freeing up memory resouces by GC.But we have not only memory resources, also having non memory resources like Database connections, network connections, file handles.So,which is also needs to be released (not just garbage-collected) when you're finished with it.

So, My question is, what are the problems we may face if we not handling(freeing) non-memory resources in java?

Please guide me to get out of clear idea about this...

Comment: It is very usefull question.It will help to java developers to improve their skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example is that.
When you use some APIs like FileInputStream.This is the one of the non-memo resource as you call.When you finish reading something from a file,and you forget to close it,then the system will occupy this file util the programs ends.During the occupation period,you may NOT open this file.That's the problems.

Comment: He means that the GC may be freeing "allocated memory" but it may well not be freeing more complex system resources such as file handles, which may cause a file to become unaccessible in either read or write (or both) access until your program exits (at which point the operating system forcibly releases all file handles in use). This is inconvenient so it is important to close your file handles as soon as you are done using the file, so that other programs may access it freely. Same with network connections, if you leave a bound port active no other program can bind to that port, etc..

Comment: My opinion is also the "Broad Lin" answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are making things complicate. When you design a program in Java, you should leaves such non-memory resources management to OS or other application as much as possible. Which means you can just shutdown the JVM without considering filehandlers, DB connections. OS will recycle filehandlers and DB will recycle non-active connections,appserver will recycle network connections...... Believe me, OS , databases and popular network apps are smarter than you think.

Comment: an application/jvm might not be shutdown for days; having the db connection or file handle unnecessaarily open is an utter waste of resource. Instead, connection pools should be used (or db connections closed in finally block), file handles should be closed in finally et-all; that is why these are supported by the api.

Comment: Hey, if you are talking about connection pooling or some other teches which every body knows we should have in a java program, I guess this is not what Saravanan is asking for.

Comment: @Saravanan wants to know how to release resources outside the JVM,which I think is not a problem to worry about.